# Track PHP GET requests

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

Is it any way for me to track a php $_GET requests in Google Analytics or maybe without it. 
I need to know how many times user clicked on `www.mywebsite.com?key=1`.
So how many users clicked on get request?

I know that i can write some php code and track if ( isset GET )... and write it to database. 
But, is it any way to do simpler and without it. It's WordPress website.

Thanks!

Comment: If you do not want to outsource or use a database, potentially Memcache is a solution? Using an MVC design, having all requests go through a router will help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it to a file

index.php would need to have something like this:

```
$value= $_GET['key'];
file_put_contents('clicks.txt', $value. PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

And every click would add the key to the bottom of mywebsite.com/clicks.txt

clicks.txt would be a simple log file, but you could move it to Excel or some other program to work with the data (or write some code to count the number of each type).

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
for more info

**Edit**
You could create a csv file (possible to open in Excel) with date/time using something like this.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$value= $_GET['key'];
$line = $date->format('Y-m-d') . ',' . $date->format('H:i:s') . ',' . $value. PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('clicks.txt', $line, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```